# HTML/JavaScript: Two dropdown list for time that dependent to each other

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm new in js. Currently, I create two dropdown list which is, 'Start Time' and 'End Time'. This dropdown list will display all hour with 24 formats and an interval of 30 minutes.

From the above situation, if I select the time from dropdown list 'Start Time' with value '10:00', the second dropdown will display a list of time with bigger than'10:00'.

and, the second dropdown list is disabled if the first dropdown list is unselected

Can anyone teaches me?

below is my current code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <body>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputCity1">Start Time</label>
      <?php get_times( $default = '00:00', $interval = '+30 minutes' )?>
      <select class="form-control" id="starttime" name="timeFrom"><?php echo get_times(); ?></select>
    </div><br><br>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputCity1">End Time</label>
      <?php get_times( $default = '00:00', $interval = '+30 minutes' )?>
      <select class="form-control" id="endtime" name="timeTo"><?php echo get_times(); ?></select>
    </div>

    <!-- Function to call time -->
    <?php
    function get_times( $default = '00:00', $interval = '+30 minutes' ) {
        $output = '';
        $current = strtotime( '00:00' );
        $end = strtotime( '23:59' );

        while( $current <= $end ) {
            $time = date( 'H:i:s', $current );
            $sel = ( $time == $default ) ? ' selected' : '';
            $output .= "<option value=\"{$time}\"{$sel}>" . date( 'H:i ', $current ) . '</option>';
            $current = strtotime( $interval, $current );
        }
        return $output;
    }
    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is tagged `javascript` but your code is PHP. Are you looking for a PHP solution or a JavaScript solution?

Comment: javascript. the php just function to get list the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jquery for this. The modified code is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <body>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputCity1">Start Time</label>
      <?php get_times( $default = '00:00', $interval = '+30 minutes' )?>
      <select class="form-control" id="starttime" name="timeFrom"><?php echo get_times(); ?></select>
    </div><br><br>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputCity1">End Time</label>
      <?php get_times( $default = '00:00', $interval = '+30 minutes' )?>
      <select class="form-control" id="endtime" name="timeTo" disabled=""><?php echo get_times(); ?></select>
    </div>

    <!-- Function to call time -->
    <?php
    function get_times( $default = '00:00', $interval = '+30 minutes' ) {
        $output = '';
        $current = strtotime( '00:00' );
        $end = strtotime( '23:59' );

        while( $current <= $end ) {
            $time = date( 'H:i:s', $current );
            $sel = ( $time == $default ) ? ' selected' : '';
            $output .= "<option value=\"{$time}\"{$sel}>" . date( 'H:i ', $current ) . '</option>';
            $current = strtotime( $interval, $current );
        }
        return $output;
    }
    ?>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $('#starttime').change(function(){
        var starttime = $(this).val();
        console.log(starttime);
        $('#endtime option').each(function(){
          if($(this).text() < starttime){
            $(this).remove();
          }
        });
        $('#endtime').removeAttr('disabled')
      })
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default disable end time dropdown. Onchange of start time call javascript function to enable end time dropdown. Try below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <body>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputCity1">Start Time</label>
      <?php get_times( $default = '00:00', $interval = '+30 minutes' ); ?>
      <select class="form-control" id="starttime" name="timeFrom" onchange="setEndTime(this.value)">
      <option value="">Select Start Time</option>
      <?php echo get_times(); ?></select>
    </div><br><br>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputCity1">End Time</label>
      <?php get_times( $default = '00:00', $interval = '+30 minutes' )?>
      <select class="form-control" id="endtime" name="timeTo" disabled>
      <option value="">Select End Time</option>  
      <?php echo get_times(); ?></select>
    </div>

    <!-- Function to call time -->
    <?php

    function get_times( $default = '00:00', $interval = '+30 minutes' ) {
        $output = '';
        $current = strtotime( '00:00' );
        $end = strtotime( '23:59' );

        while( $current <= $end ) {
            $time = date( 'H:i:s', $current );
            $sel = ( $time == $default ) ? ' selected' : '';
            $output .= "<option value=\"{$time}\"{$sel}>" . date( 'H:i ', $current ) . '</option>';
            $current = strtotime( $interval, $current );
        }
        return $output;
    }
    ?>

    </body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function setEndTime(start_time){
        if(start_time){
          $("#endtime").prop('disabled', false);

          $('#endtime option').filter(function() {
              return $(this).val() <= start_time;
          }).prop('disabled', true);
        }else{
          $("#endtime").prop('disabled', true);
        }
    }
    </script>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

select class="form-control" id="endtime" name="timeTo" disabled>//disable attribute on page load

Include jquery library file first. Then include this script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

          $("#starttime").change(function(){ // on change of selectbox startime



            $("#endtime").prop('disabled', false); // it will active endtime selectbox


            $("#endtime option").each(function(){ // get all option value of endtime

              if($(this).val() <= $("#starttime").val()){

                $(this).prop('disabled', true); // compare with starttime and disable if value is less or equal to starttime
              }

            });



          });

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily control select options by generating options with javascript.
Heres my code:

```js
(function() {

let times = [
    '',
    '00:00',
    '00:30',
    '01:00',
    '01:30',
    '02:00',
    '02:30',
    '03:00',
    '03:30',
    '04:00',
    '04:30',
    '05:00',
    '05:30',
    '06:00',
    '06:30',
    '07:00',
    '07:30',
    '08:00',
    '08:30',
    '09:00',
    '09:30',
    '10:00',
    '10:30',
    '11:00',
    '11:30',
    '12:00',
    '12:30',
    '13:00',
    '13:30',
    '14:00',
    '14:30',
    '15:00',
    '15:30',
    '16:00',
    '16:30',
    '17:00',
    '17:30',
    '18:00',
    '18:30',
    '19:00',
    '19:30',
    '20:00',
    '20:30',
    '21:00',
    '21:30',
    '22:00',
    '22:30',
    '23:00',
    '23:30'
];

let startSelect = document.getElementById('starttime');
let endSelect = document.getElementById('endtime');

startSelect.addEventListener('change', () => updateEndSelect());
setStartSelect();
updateEndSelect();

function setStartSelect() {
    startOptionHtml = '';
    times.forEach((time) => {
        startOptionHtml += '<option value="' + time + '">' + time + '</option>';
    });
    startSelect.innerHTML = startOptionHtml;
}

function updateEndSelect() {
    let selectedStartTime = startSelect.value;
    let selectedEndTime = endSelect.value;

    if (!selectedStartTime) {
        endSelect.disabled = true;
    } else {
        endSelect.disabled = false;
    }
    
    var endOptionHtml = '';
    times.forEach((time) => {
        var selected = '';
        if (time === selectedEndTime) {
            selected = 'selected';
        }
        if (time > selectedStartTime) {
            endOptionHtml += '<option value="' + time + '" ' + selected + '>' + time + '</option>';
        }

    });
    endSelect.innerHTML = endOptionHtml;
}

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>Start Time</label>
          <select id="starttime"></select>
      </div>
      <br>

      <div class="form-group">
          <label>End Time</label>
          <select id="endtime"></select>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```